# knockout binding is not working for enable button after ko.applyBindings in bootstrap modal

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js, binding, bootstrap-modal, enable-if

I'm trying to enable a button after check a checkbox, the elements are in a modal. I'm using MVC, and I'm adding the observables after the main binding for use them just with the modal like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Model = function () {
        self.check = ko.observable(false);   
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.cleanNode($('#Modal')[0]);
        ko.applyBindings(Model, $('#Modal')[0]);
    });

</script>
```

The html elements inside the modal look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:viewModel.check">bla bla..
<button type="button" data-bind="enable:viewModel.check==true" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>
```

when I select the checkbox the viewModel.check is true and when is not checked is false which is working fine but the button is always disable. Any advise please

Comment: It should be `<button type="button" data-bind="enable:viewModel.check" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>` or `<button type="button" data-bind="enable:viewModel.check()===true" class="btn btn-primary">Delete</button>`. Because `check` is an observable.

Comment: When  I try in that way , I get  the message that is not a function maybe I'm not using fine the scope of the bindings :/

Comment: Yes! Second one :) It should be `ko.applyBindings(new Model(), $('#Modal')[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues...

## Un-instantiated ViewModel

When calling `ko.applyBindings`, the first argument needs to be a viewModel *instance*. This means you need to call `new` on your viewModel "class."

```
ko.applyBindings(new Model())
```

## Incorrect scope in HTML

You are referencing a `viewModel` variable which does not exist. When you apply bindings, it uses the scope of the viewModel passed to in to create the binding context. This means that the values available to you in the HTML are the same as those on `this` in your viewModel. So, just use `check`.

## `enable` binding bound to expression, not observable

The enable binding must be bound to an observable, but you have bound it to the expression `check==true`. In this case, `check` is actually an observable — `this.check = ko.observable()`, so what you're ultimately comparing is something to the effect of `function() { return true } == true`, which is expectedly `false`. To do comparisons on observables, you must first unwrap them by calling them as a function: `check() == true`. Note, however, that anytime you're writing `== true`, you probably don't need to: `enable: check` is what you ultimately want.

[and a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4awLxja0/)